# Swift naming conventions for add/set methods

Tags: swift, naming-conventions

In Objective-C, you might have a method like one of these

```
-(void)addWidget(Widget*)widget classification:(WidgetClassification*)classification;

-(void)setText:(NSString*)text color(UIColor*)color style:(FontStyle)style
```

In Swift 3+, you could chose to translate the names as either this (let's call it Objective-C style):

```
func addWidget(_ widget: Widget, classification: WidgetClassification)

func setText(_ text: String, color: UIColor, style: FontStyle)
```

or this (let's call it swift 3 style)

```
func add(widget: Widget, classification: WidgetClassification)

func set(text: String, color: UIColor, style: FontStyle)
```

Personally I think the latter `set(text...` looks and feels better, however when bridging back to Objective-C, the compiler is translating it as `setWithText:(NSString*)text...` which feels a bit strange as well.

Is there an established convention for this? The `setText(_ text: String...` variant fits objective-C better, but doesn't feel like it lines up with the Swift 3 style where all parameter names are exposed

I'd appreciate any comments on this and how people feel about it

Comment: This might be of help https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Comment: I don't think naming convention questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow, as everyone holds some sort of bias to naming.

Comment: Especially in Swift, exactly this type of naming convention is being addressed in Swift documentation. This is a valid question and not opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the link to the swift api design guidelines.

While they don't explicitly spell it out, there are enough clues to be found there to make me think the creators of swift 3 definitely intend for the Objective-C naming style to still be used in these cases.

Firstly, the "Compensate for weak type information" section shows this as a "Good" example:

```
func addObserver(_ observer: NSObject, forKeyPath path: String)
grid.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: graphics) // clear
```

That didn't convince me on it's own because KVO is an objective-C thing, but further down in the Conventions / Parameters section, they show this as another "Good" example:

```
/// Replace the given `subRange` of elements with `newElements`.
mutating func replaceRange(_ subRange: Range, with newElements: [E])
```

Digging through the Array class definition for example, finds

```
public func dropLast(_ n: Int) -> ArraySlice<Element>

public func withUnsafeBytes<R>(_ body: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R
```

and a variety of similar methods, which all use the "Objective-C" naming style.

To me it seems like if the authors of swift had intended to go with my `set(x:` naming style, they would have called those methods

```
replace(subrange: Range, with newElements: [E])

drop(last n: Int)

with(unsafeBytes body: ...
```

But they didn't.

It seems like they have taken the path of "generally don't suppress the first parameter's external name, unless the grammar makes you feel like it's a better thing to do".

I guess this is probably better overall for readability, even if it requires more effort to think about.

Thanks!

Comment: As Alexander showed below, the api design guidelines do mention that, at least for remove and probably add, you should leave the type out.

Answer (score 2):

> - **Omit needless words.** Every word in a name should convey salient
>     information at the use site.
>
>   More words may be needed to clarify intent or disambiguate meaning,
>     but those that are redundant with information the reader already
>     possesses should be omitted. In particular, omit words that *merely
>     repeat* type information.
>
>   ```
>   public mutating func removeElement(_ member: Element) -> Element?
>
>   allViews.removeElement(cancelButton) In this case, the word `Element`
>   ```
>
>   adds nothing salient at the call site. This API would be better:
>
>   ```
>   public mutating func remove(_ member: Element) -> Element?
>
>   allViews.remove(cancelButton) // clearer Occasionally, repeating type
>   ```
>
>   information is necessary to avoid ambiguity, but in general it is
>     better to use a word that describes a parameter’s role rather than its
>     type. See the next item for details.

from https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/